# Matplotlib doesn't show line marker

Tags: matplotlib, plot, marker

I am using matplotlib to create a chart but when I use 'bo--' or 'bo-' or other ways to define line marker the plot doesn't show the line. I can see the line in legend but not the chart. I also installed the last version but nothing changed.

```
plt.plot(this_alpha, r2_test, 'bo-')
plt.plot(this_alpha, r2_train, 'ro-')
```

[image: this is the plot]

Comment: what does your data look like? Does it have any `NaN`s in it?

Comment: No, it doesn't have na values.